# How to Add Return-Path Mail Header using SendGrid

Tags: sendgrid, return-path

I am sending emails from Azure Webjob (C#) via SendGrid. I don't see any option to add Return-Path in the mail header. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, SendGrid controls the Return-Path, and overwrites it to be what they need it to be for bounce management.

If you need it to stay original, you'd have to contact their Support team to disable that setting.

If you just need to get bounce backs, you can set those up using [Bounce Forwarding](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200181478-How-to-set-up-bounce-forwarding-to-go-to-the-email-s-FROM-address), or get allthedata with [Event Webhook](https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/200182028-Why-Event-API-).

Comment: This is all true. But it should be noted that if you have a custom return path (which contains recipient ID, source ID, etc.) then this won't work. You'll have to parse everything from the contents of the bounce message. The bounce API only gives you a few pieces of info. I'm encountering this while moving from our own mail server to SendGrid.

Comment: True, but you could also pass all those IDs in the [Unique Args/Custom Args](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/unique_arguments.html), which will come back in the Event Webhook.

Comment: @jacobmovingfwd are you sure that is the case? currently all the bounce events being sent to our webhook are missing the unique args, any ideas?

Comment: @Ben that can sometimes happen for some "delayed" types of bounces, but shouldn't be happening for all your bounces. If you're seeing that, I would reach out to SendGrid Support.